# Custom authentication in WCF through basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, authentication, configuration

I have my WCF working. I have the following configuration for it:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="HttpStreaming" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" closeTimeout="00:05:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="65536000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        </security>
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CifsManager.CifsManagerServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CifsManager.CifsManagerServiceBehavior" name="CifsManager.CifsManagerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpStreaming" contract="CifsManager.ICifsManagerService"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

I generated the proxy class for calling the service **ServiceClient** and I call it in the following way:

```
var service = new ServiceClient();
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "111";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "111";
service.bufferSize = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BufferSize"]);
var file= service.GetFile();
```

[Here](http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?tag=usernameauthentication) I found the articles where it is described how to solve my problem throught the **wsHttpBinding**, but using it I get the server error. Could I create the authentication using the **basicHttpBinding** or I need the **wsHttpBinding** and how should I do it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You'll want to keep in mind that if you use basicHttpBinding and try and pass credentials, they'll be passed in plain text over the wire and therefore be able to be intercepted...

Comment: So it is not good idea to use basicHttpBinding, isn't it?
And what binding should I use in this case?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `WsHttpBinding` - then for security you can use `Transport`, `Message` or `TransportWithMessageCredential`.  You can read about the differences between these here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. Could you please tell me if I should use certificate using WsHttpBinding. Because after your post I'm trying to use this and getting the error **The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.**
could I somehow avoid this certificate?

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to use any of those security methods without a cert.  You can find links to more information on securing WCF services in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054166/authentication-in-wcf-for-every-call/8067400#8067400

Comment: Thanks for the information. You are right these security methods need a cert. And in the case that I'll use **basicHttpBinding** and pass my credential with a plain text, can I transport with not **HTTPS** but **HTTP**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to condense all of this into an answer so it's all in one place and easier to find instead of spread out amidst comments.  Using `BasicHttpBinding` means that your credentials will be passed in plaintext over the wire, meaning they could be intercepted along the way without much trouble.  You can avoid this problem by using `WsHttpBinding`, which allows you to use one of three different security types: `Transport`, `Message`, or `TransportWithMessageCredential`.  You can read about these [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx).  Keep in mind, however, that with any of these you'll have to have a certificate of one form or another.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054166/authentication-in-wcf-for-every-call) question has a brief discussion of some other WCF security options.  If you're dead set on using `BasicHttpBinding` and passing your credentials over the wire, you could at least consider masking them somehow before doing so, perhaps an sha1 with a salt or something similar.  If you don't want to use any of the built-in and done solutions that are available like ASP.NET Membership, you'll have to figure out on your own what kind of an auth token you want to pass back and forth.